# How does MarkDig UseSoftlineBreakAsHardlineBreak extension work?

Tags: c#, .net, markdown

Markdig is a popular mardown processer for .net.  When setting up the pipeline for markdig one of the options is "Soft lines as hard lines" which can be configured by using like so

```
var pipeline = new MarkdownPipelineBuilder()
                  .UseSoftlineBreakAsHardlineBreak()
                  .Build();
```

And according to the [documentation](https://github.com/lunet-io/markdig/blob/master/src/Markdig.Tests/Specs/HardlineBreakSpecs.md) "When this extension is used, a new line in a paragraph block will result in a hardline break"

```
This is a paragraph
with a break inside
.
<p>This is a paragraph<br />
with a break inside</p>
```

However when I try using this extension, the behavior I observe is different than that cited in the example.  The output I observe is the same as without the extension, which is:

```
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<p>with a break inside</p>
```

Somehow I don't think I'm understanding this `UseSoftlineBreakAsHardlineBreak` extension properly.  Can someone explain what I'm seeing verses the example in the docs cited?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is in understanding the difference between insignificant whitespace and significant whitespace in HTML. The [normal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#Values) behavior is described this way:

> Sequences of white space are collapsed. Newline characters in the source are handled the same as other white space. Lines are broken as necessary to fill line boxes.

Therefore, this paragraph:

```html
<p>This is a paragraph
with a break inside</p>
```

is rendered as:

> This is a paragraph
>   with a break inside

If you use your browser's "view source" or "inspect" tool, you can see that the line break is preserved in the HTML, but gets treated as a space by the browser. The `UseSoftlineBreakAsHardlineBreak` extension inserts a `<br />` element, so that the browser preserves the line break.

In other words, with `UseSoftlineBreakAsHardlineBreak`, the HTML output becomes:

```html
<p>This is a paragraph<br />
with a break inside</p>
```

which is rendered as:

> This is a paragraph
>   with a break inside

Note that preserving line breaks like this is a non-standard Markdown behavior, but is often less surprising to users who are not familiar with how browsers handle whitespace.

---

Finally, I note that in the question you present the normal output (without `UseSoftlineBreakAsHardlineBreak`) as this:

```html
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<p>with a break inside</p>
```

rather than the expected output:

```html
<p>This is a paragraph
with a break inside</p>
```

I assume that was a mistake/oversight on your part when creating your question. If you really are getting two separate paragraphs (one for each line), then that is a separate issue altogether and should probably be its own question.

Comment: Your answer helped me take a closer look at what I *thought* I was seeing.  In the end, I wasn't understanding that a line break which occurs after other non-whitespace chars turns into a <br> but a line break that is on it's own line or which follows only whitespace does not produce a `<br>` and still causes any later text to be in a new set of `<p></p>` tags.  That's the important distinction I was missing.